# CSS style is creating a hover box next to my a tag, rather than over it

Tags: html, css, hover

[image]I am completely stumped - I am following along on an online course and cannot pick what is different to my teacher.
I am attempting to have a green colored box over each of the links when you hover over them. Currently I get the box but only to the left of the link

Tried to share full HTML and CSS but too large, question wouldn't post. Please let me know if you need more information thanks

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}  

#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: #93cb52;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <nav id="navbar">
    <h1 class="logo">
    <span class="text-primary">
      <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i> Edge 
    </span>Ledger
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home"></a>Home</li>
      <li><a href="#what"></a>What</li>
      <li><a href="#who"></a>Who</li>
      <li><a href="#contact"></a>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not far off! I think your issue is that you haven't placed the link text inside the link. For example `Home` should be inside the `a` element, not to the right of it. So `<li><a href="#home"></a>Home</li>` should become `<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>`.

This will cause underlines to appear on the links, which you can disable by adding `text-decoration: none` to your `#navbar ul li a` selector.

Full code will look like:

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}  

#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: #93cb52;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <nav id="navbar">
    <h1 class="logo">
    <span class="text-primary">
      <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i> Edge 
    </span>Ledger
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#what">What</a></li>
      <li><a href="#who">Who</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Brilliant. You should mark this as the answer so that people know the post is solved.

Comment: Sorry I did try originally but it told me to wait 4 mins ?? but has worked now. Forgive me pls I'm a newbie

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo in your code

In your html you should put link text inside `a` tag not inside `li` tag

So do that

```
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<! - - instead of doing that
  <li><a href="#home"></a>Home</li>
-->
```